Why is Clipboard.SetTextAsync not working on Android in .NET MAUI but works on Windows?
I am developing a .NET MAUI application where I need to copy text to the clipboard. The implementation works perfectly on Windows, but it fails to copy the text on Android devices. Below is the relevant code and the manifest file with the necessary permissions.
using TextRecognizer.Services;
using Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

namespace TextRecognizer.Views;

public partial class ScanResPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly IOcrResultService _ocrResultService;

    public ScanResPage(IOcrResultService ocrResultService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _ocrResultService = ocrResultService;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await LoadResultsAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadResultsAsync()
    {
        var results = await _ocrResultService.GetResultsAsync();
        var displayResults = results.Select(text => new DisplayResult { FullText = text, DisplayText = GetDisplayText(text) }).ToList();
        ResultsCollectionView.ItemsSource = displayResults;
    }

    private string GetDisplayText(string text)
    {
        const int maxLength = 100; // Show only the first 100 characters
        return text.Length <= maxLength ? text : text.Substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
    }

    private async void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() is DisplayResult selectedResult)
        {
            try
            {
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Clipboard.Default.SetTextAsync(selectedResult.FullText);
                });
                await DisplayAlert("Copied", "Text copied to clipboard.", "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", $"Clipboard error: {ex.Message}", "OK");
            }

            await Task.Delay(300);
            ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }

    private async void ClearResults_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await _ocrResultService.ClearResultsAsync();
        await LoadResultsAsync();
    }

    public class DisplayResult
    {
        public string? FullText { get; set; }
        public string? DisplayText { get; set; }
    }
}


The text is successfully copied to the clipboard on Windows, but it does not get copied on Android. I have ensured that all necessary permissions are granted in the Android manifest file. I have also wrapped the clipboard operation in MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread.
What could be causing this issue on Android, and how can I resolve it to ensure the text gets copied to the clipboard on Android devices?

I have no experience with .NET MAUI, however the call BeginInvokeOnMainThread returns void and doesn't report on the completion of the Acton delegate.
Consider using InvokeOnMainThreadAsync instead and awaiting the returned Task, perhaps the Action delegate hasn't completed execution.

I'm using it in .net8.0 like the following
(Android/iOS : OK) (Windows : Not tested)
Full Path:  Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard
#region Copy To Clipboard
[RelayCommand]
public async Task CopyAsync(XModel_View_T_Medical_Report t_Order)
{
    if (t_Order is not null)
    {
        await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(t_Order.M_REPORT);
        await Show_ToastAsync($"Copied to clipboard !");
    }
}
#endregion

